# Stack overflow when trying to return a unique pointer with VS2015 and addrinfoW

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have done some code to retrieve addresses from a DNS, and I have a crash happening.
Here is my code:

```
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <winSock2.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <memory>
#include <random>

bool resolveHost(const wchar_t* hostname, uint16_t port);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WSADATA wsaData;

    WSAStartup(
      MAKEWORD(2,2),
      &wsaData
    );
    auto l = resolveHost(L"your own DNS here", 80);
}

std::unique_ptr<addrinfoW, decltype (&FreeAddrInfoW)> getAddrInfo(const wchar_t* hostname, quint16 defaultPort)
{
    addrinfoW* result;
    // zero initialization
    addrinfoW hints = {};
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    wchar_t port[9];
    int error = swprintf_s(port, sizeof (port), L"%hu", defaultPort);
    if(error == -1)
    {
        printf("Invalid call to swprintf_s");
        return std::unique_ptr<addrinfoW, decltype (&FreeAddrInfoW)>{nullptr, &FreeAddrInfoW};
    }
    /* resolve the domain name into a list of addresses */
    error = GetAddrInfoW(hostname, port, &hints, &result);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        wprintf(gai_strerror(error));
        return std::unique_ptr<addrinfoW, decltype (&FreeAddrInfoW)>{nullptr, &FreeAddrInfoW};
    }
// here, when I return, I have a stack overflow
    return std::move(std::unique_ptr<addrinfoW, decltype (&FreeAddrInfoW)>{result, &FreeAddrInfoW});
}

bool resolveHost(const wchar_t hostname, uint16_t port)
{
    auto guard {getAddrInfo(hostname, port)};
    return true;
}
```

When getAddrInfo returns, I have a stack overflow with VS 2015 (I don't have another version), and I don't understand why. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass array size in bytes instead of array elements count in `swprintf_s` which may cause stack corruption. In debug mode it fills the rest of the buffer after terminating null with [garbage marker 0xFE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/7860670). Note that there is an appropriate overload for `swprintf_s` deducing size of the c-style array so there is no need to pass it explicitly.

Also there should be no `std::move(` in the last return statement.

Comment: IOW, `sizeof(port)` is `sizeof(wchar_t)*9=18`, so you are telling `swprintf_s()` it is OK to write up to 18 characters into the `port` buffer, but it can only hold 9 characters. But, I don't see how this can cause a stack corruption since `"%hu"` would produce only 5 formatted characters + a null terminator, which is well within `port`'s allocated memory. `swprintf_s()` doesn't null out unused characters, unlike `wcsncpy_s()` for instance. But VTT is correct, you should use the overloaded `swprintf_s()` that deduces the buffer size for you: `int error = swprintf_s(port, L"%hu", defaultPort);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau In debug mode it fills remaining part (after terminating null) of the buffer with 0xFE.

Comment: Good to know, thanks, That should be included in your answer